# How to find out computer architecture WITHOUT access to Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cpu-architecture

**NOTE:** I *do* have access in File Explorer to browse the entire filesystem.

Extra details: I am at a library in my school running Windows 7 Enterprise. I am bored, so I am trying to figure out ways to do more interesting things on it. I am trying to install a runtime ([this](http://archon-runtime.github.io/), if you really want to know) as an extension on Google Chrome, but it needs to know what architecture the computer is running on. I figured out how to run cmd and become the admin, but I do not want to become the admin because that's a little too risky.

Comment: Take a look at [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Comment: If you are running Windows then its x86-64 since that's the only type of architecture Windows 7 runs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access a command prompt, open one and run the systeminfo command like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I was able to find out that my school computers were running x86. (I think your image got removed, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on My Computer and select Properties. A window will pop up with system information. The "System Type" will be either 32 bit / x86 OR 64 bit / x64 operating system. You can then choose the relevant runtime version from the ARChon download page.